# How do I set "Show print margin" for my group?

Tags: eclipse

Eclipse will place a light gray line on a column you choose when you select from Preferences > General > Editors > Text Editors and check the "Show print margin" checkbox.

If I add this line to my Checkstyle external file:

```
<setting id="org.eclipse.jdt.core.formatter.lineSplit" value="150"/>
```

then Format (Ctrl-Shift-F) will do a good job in splitting lines before column 150.

Is there a means, such as an XML file, in which I might set the value of the text editor "Show print margin"? I would like my department to have the formatter split lines at 150 (can do) and have all Eclipse IDEs show the gray line at column 150 (don't know how).

I have tried toggling the "Show print margin" checkbox and even checking "Show line numbers," but I cannot find a file that Eclipse altered, in either my Eclipse executable path or my project files that reflects this change. It must to be stored somewhere: these persists across Eclipse sessions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you change your settings via the Preference menu, you are changing the workspace settings. The files you are looking for are therefore located in the `.metadata` directory of your workspace. The specific file you are looking for is

```
.metadata/.plugins/org.eclipse.core.runtime/.settings/org.eclipse.ui.editors.prefs
```

This file can contain the following two lines:

```
printMarginColumn=120
printMargin=true
```

If `printMarginColumn` is not present, the default seems to be `80`.

If you change the settings on a project, the file is the same but the location is in your project's `.settings` directory.